# How to view all emails in inbox for my gmail

Tags: gmail

When a "spam" email comes, I would rather just delete it than let it sit in my spam. What I would prefer is that regardless of whether I am on my phone, computer, etc. when *any* email comes, it goes into my inbox, where I can review it and keep it/delete it. Is there any way to do this? (I would prefer not to periodically visit the all mail tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gmail to skip the SPAM folder for all incoming messages you will need to create a Filter.

### Create Filter

1. Open Gmail settings in a web browser on a computer:
   https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters
2. Click on the **'Create a new filter'** link part way down the page.
3. On the line **'Has the words'** enter both the minus sign as well as the word beside it with no spaces:
   **-supercalifragilisticexpialidocious**
4. Click **'Create Filter'**
5. Check the box beside **'Never send it to Spam'**
6. Click **'Create Filter'**

Moving forward if a spammer, scammer, hacker, phisher, etc. manages somehow to fall into your suspected SPAM folder it is because they are quoting Mary Poppins lyrics.

Normal people quoting Mary Poppins lyrics will likely still end up in your inbox since the rule doesn't send any emails to SPAM, it only makes a hard exception for all messages that match the rule.  I expect this should cover close to 100% of your emails with a possible exception of maybe 1 per 1,789,652,411 give or take.

Comment: lol why not just put some random gibberish to avoid even that 1/1789652411 chance :P

Comment: I like to live dangerously :-)